# Submit form data to Highcharts addPoint method to dynamically update form

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I currently have a chart pulling in data from a local JSON file. I now need to submit data via a form to update the chart dynamically. I know Highcharts has an addPoint method which should work, just need some guidance on how to pass my form data to this method.

```
  <form id="add_data">
    <p>
      <input type="date" name="date" id="human" value="date" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="integer" name="amount" id="amount" value="amount" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="request_type" id="human" value="human" />
      <label for="human">Human</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="request_type" id="good" value="good" />
      <label for="good">Good</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="request_type" id="bad" value="bad" />
      <label for="bad">Bad</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="request_type" id="whitelist" value="whitelist" />
      <label for="whitelist">Whitelist</label>
    </p>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

The Highcharts docs use this as an example, which is what I am trying to use, but instead of hard coding the data I need to pass in my form data. I think...if I am totally off please let me know. Any help is appreciated.

```
$('#add_data   input:radio[name=request_type]').click(function() {
  $index = $('#add_data input:radio[name=request_type]').index(this);
});

$('#submit').click(function() {
  var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
    amount = parseFloat($('#amount').val());
  chart.series[$index].addPoint(amount);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your click action you need to extract values from inputs. For example if you need to add point with value from input AMOUNT it should be used like:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
        point = parseFloat($('#amount').val());

    chart.series[0].addPoint(point);
    i += 1;
});
```

Comment: Great thank you, going to test it out and report back.

Comment: Ok that is working, thank you. I also need update which series the data is being added to. I updated my code above, I know that it's missing a few things and has some scoping issues, but maybe you can tell me if I am going in the right direction? Basically trying to grab the index of the radio button so I can pass that into `chart.series[put index here].addPoint(point)`.

Comment: I am now able to add it to the correct series, I think the next step is to submit via ajax so the page doesn't reload? Right now it adds the point, reloads and the new data disappears.

Comment: In case when you add point, what should be next action? why you need to use ajax etc ?

Comment: I'm not really sure on the next action. All of my data is being loaded from a json file, this new point is not being saved anywhere, so saving it?

Comment: Maybe I ask you differently, you have a form, values from form should be added to chart as points and that is all or you need more actions?